# Closed form for $a+ar^nq+ar^{n-1}q^2+\cdots+ar^2q^{n-1}+arq^n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I know that the formula for a geometric series
$$a + ar + ar^2 + \cdots + ar^n$$
is $a(\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r})$, but I am trying to solve a different type of series which "combines" two geometric series together:
$$s = a + ar^nq + ar^{n-1}q^2 + \cdots + ar^2q^{n-1} + arq^n$$
Would this require a more advanced solution?

I've tried to multiply by $q$ such that
$$qs = aq + ar^nq^2 + ar^{n-1}q^3 + \cdots + ar^2q^n + arq^{n+1}$$
and subtract it from the original sum, but it doesn't neatly cancel out like a regular geometric sum.

Comment: What is the common ratio here?

Comment: Note that the $a$ is irrelevant so we may as well consider the series $$t = \sum_{k=1}^n q^{k} r^{n- k +1} = r^{n+1} \sum_{k=1}^n (q/r)^k.$$

Comment: "*I've tried to multiply by q ... and subtract it*" That won't work because the common ratio is not $q$. Instead, try to multiply by $q$ and $r$, respectively, then subtract the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide the sum by $r^{n+1}$ and compute the resulting geometric sum.

Comment: Thanks @Bennie. This and Gregory's comment made me see it clearly.